# dynamically creation of subproject which can be access by subdomain based on different user

Tags: java

I have a project in Java EE. I want to change the logo and background color of the project based on the user. For example :

If the url is: www.xyz.com --> then it should open the project with a default logo and background.

But if the url is: abc.xyz.com or xyz.com/abc --> then it should open the project with the logo and background specific to `abc`.

Here `abc` is the user name which can be created dynamically. I want to know that if we will create a user then how we can access the same project with the url like username.xyz.com or xyz.com/username.

Answer (score 1):

I think a good solution is to configure your app to behave like you want with the `http://appUrl/username` url and then use an `apache http` server as a proxy to route calls to `http://username.appUrl` to `http://appUrl/username` .

In order to achieve the `http://appUrl/username` you can just map your application to treat anything mapped to `/*` and treat anything following the first `/` as a parameter. This can be achieved using basic servlet mapping or, for example, `Spring MVC`.

Comment: I am facing one problem like : lets assume i have an application where we can create user dynamically. based on that user we are assigning some background image and color. i want to create one specific url for different user like : http://appUrl/Username. But all the url should point to same application. Based on the username we have to change the images, background color of the page. So, please suggest how we will achieve this functionality.